# Conditional grouping with mean and count

Tags: python, pandas

I want to elaborate the grouping logic as follows. Given the dataframe `df`:

```
df =

    ID  GROUP  DAY  GRADE  TIME_1
    1   AAA    1    5      20
    1   AAA    1    4      19
    1   AAA    1    3      21
    1   BBB    2    1      10
    2   BBB    2    3      13
```

I need to group rows by `ID`, `GRADE`, `GROUP` and `DAY`, and calculate mean `TIME_1`, count of rows in a group. Also (and this is my question), I want to check if `GRADE` is 4 or 5, then it should be grouped as a positive grade and mean `TIME_1` should be calculated per it, otherwise - as negative.

The result should be this one:

```
result =

    GROUP  DAY  AVG_TIME_1_POSITIVE  AVG_TIME_1_NEGATIVE  QTY_POSITIVE   QTY_NEGATIVE
    AAA    1    19.5                 21                   2              1
    BBB    2    0                    11.5                 0              2
```

I use this approach, but don't know how to specify the grouping condition by `GRADE`:

```
result = df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE','DAY']).agg({'TIME_1': 'mean', 
                     'ID': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
mask = df.GRADE.isin([4,5])
result1 = df[mask].groupby(['GROUP','DAY']).agg({'TIME_1': 'mean', 
                     'ID': 'count'}).add_suffix('_POSITIVE')

print (result1)
           TIME_1_POSITIVE  ID_POSITIVE
GROUP DAY                              
AAA   1               19.5            2

result2 = df[~mask].groupby(['GROUP','DAY']).agg({'TIME_1': 'mean', 
                     'ID': 'count'}).add_suffix('_NEGATIVE')

print (result2)
           TIME_1_NEGATIVE  ID_NEGATIVE
GROUP DAY                              
AAA   1               21.0            1
BBB   2               11.5            2

print (pd.concat([result1, result2], axis=1))
           TIME_1_POSITIVE  ID_POSITIVE  TIME_1_NEGATIVE  ID_NEGATIVE
GROUP DAY                                                            
AAA   1               19.5          2.0             21.0            1
BBB   2                NaN          NaN             11.5            2
```

Comment: Hard question without your data. Is `print (type(mask))` - `Series` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass functions to `agg` something like

```
qty_pos = df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE','DAY']).agg({'GRADE': lambda x: sum(x>3)})
qty_neg = df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE','DAY']).agg({'GRADE': lambda x: sum(x<=3)})
result['QTY_POSITIVE'] = qty_pos
result['QTY_NEGATIV'] = qty_neg
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it is not pythonic if you have to manually split, apply and combine the dataframe after you have used groupby (which is supposed to do the split-apply-combine job for us). So I think the problem is how to formulate a proper key for the dataframe to group.

Input:

```
df=df.set_index(['GROUP','DAY', 'GRADE'],drop=False)
key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1], 'positive' if x[2] in [4,5] else 'negative')
df.groupby(key).agg({'TIME_1': 'mean', 'ID': 'count'})
```

Output:

```
                   TIME_1   ID
(AAA, 1, negative)  21.0    1
(AAA, 1, positive)  19.5    2
(BBB, 2, negative)  11.5    2
```